# Using sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice to get data from two tables

Tags: forms, widget, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a working selection list using sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice:

```
$this->widgetSchema['program_choice'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
   'label' => 'Program',
   'model' => 'Program', 
   'add_empty' => true,
   'method' => 'formatProgramWithSectionTitle',
   'order_by' => array('title', 'asc')
), array('class' => 'select_program size-300'));
```

This return a select list with all programs in the model.

I would like to extend this to query another table and pull those entries into the selection list. Can this be done using the sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice widget, or should I switch to the sfWidgetFormChoice widget and build my list in a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should use `sfWidgetFormChoice`